# Visual studio 2008. I cant remember hot to do the things

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I am helping a friend with his C# homework, but is being a long time since i don't do nothing in .NET Could you please me give me a hand to solve some difficulties i have with visual studio 2008?

**Problem 1**

How can i make a primary key of a table be auto incremented automatically? Where is that option? i don't see it in my interface anywhere.

[image]

**Problem 2**

How can i create a relationship between 2 tables? I think i am doing it correctly, but i don't see any sign that i did things right:

This is how i start creating the relationship:
[image]

Then i configure the relationship with the wizard:
[image]

But at the end i don't see any icon or symbol that indicates me that this is a relationship:
[image]

**Problem 3**

I want to start adding data in the database directly in the easiest and fastest way(Executing an Insert query). Could you give me a little tip on how to do that?(I don't want other approaches such as dataset...)

Comment: re: Problem3 > do you want to know how to insert large amount of data using an Insert query? or through a language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem1:

Set the isIdentity to 'Yes'
Set IdentityIncrement to '1' (it means it will add 1 to the id for every new row)
Set IdentitySeed to '0' (it means it will start with 0 ..then 1 ..then 2 ...so on)

Problem2:

Your doing it pretty much correctly. You won't see an icon or anything but once you right-click and go to Relationships. On the left hand table you can see the relationship was created (`FK_learner_student`) ,

Take a look at this video after the 2:00 mark > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXz5fpoopNo . It's doing exactly the same. Or this official tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx